# My thumb drive became corrupted and reads RAW now can I recover info

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

Inserting a thumbdrive i have been using for the past year - I get an alert that the drive is not formatted and is requesting to format the thumb drive. I did a recovery run and it showed up as RAW. i have tons of material on it, is there a way to recover my data?